# SPRING - Named JDBC template not working if the query has double quotes

Tags: spring-jdbc

I'm writing this query :

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_NAME = 'TEST''s' AND STUDENT_ID = :ID;
```

Executing the above query using named JdbcTemplate having the value of ID in the namedparametermap is throwing me the below mentioned exception :

> nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter
>   at index:: 1

NOTE: The double quote in the name is to escape single quotes.

Comment: Can you show us some code where the query is used ?

Comment: String query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_NAME = 'TEST''s' AND STUDENT_ID = :ID"; 
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("ID","1344");
 List<Map<String, Object>> data =getNamedJdbctemplate().queryForList(query,paramSource);

Comment: getNamedJdbctemplate holds the jdbctemplate reference